Create iOS distribution certificate is greyed out in Visual Studio 2022
I have Visual Studio 2022 and a MAUI application I have developed.
I need to distribute it now, so I enrolled in the apple developer program as an organization.
When I try to create a certificate using Visual Studio, iOS distribution certificate is mnot available.
What is it going on here? And most importantly, how to fix this.

I don't know if this may be the cause, but wheen I see tje team role, I see that it is set as agent.


From the Create a signing certificate document,

If an option in the drop-down is greyed out and unselected, it means that you don't have the correct team permissions to create this type of certificate.

So you may try using Admin role (as shown in the doc ) to create the distribution certificate
Here's the Apple documentation to
Change team member roles

For  Apple Developer Enterprise Program,

The Apple Developer Enterprise Program is only for the internal use and distribution of proprietary apps in specific use cases that are not adequately addressed with public apps on the App Store, custom apps through Apple Business Manager or Ad Hoc distribution, or beta testing through TestFlight. Your proprietary app must be developed by you for use on Apple platforms.

And for Roles for the Apple Developer Enterprise Program

Note: Since this program doesn’t include App Store distribution, membership benefits don’t include access to App Store Connect. User management is done in the People section of your account.

App Store distribution is not included in Apple Developer Enterprise Program. So you don't have the permission to create one.
For more info, you may refer to Program Roles.

That's the problem, I think. In my users and access page, I have Account Holder and Admin roles. However, when I add my account to Visual Studio, my team appears with a role called "agent", however, that role is not even listed in the program roles page.

Do you use Apple Developer Enterprise Program? The Apple Developer Enterprise Program is only for the internal use and distribution of proprietary apps in specific use cases that are not adequately addressed with public apps on the App Store...  That may be the reason why the ios distribution certificate is greyed out

No.... I enrolled to the normal program.

Do you enroll as Individual for Apple Developer Program?

As an organization, but not enterprise program.

When you  create App Store Connect API Team key on Apple Store Connect, do you set the Access as Admin?

I didn't have one. I created a team key and I assigned Admin. Then, I downloaded the certificate, but, what should I do then? I opened visual studio and in Apple Account options, I cannot choose that certificate to create an enterprise account. I could add an individual account with that certificate. But  iOS distribution is not enabled either. I have realized that downloaded key has p8 extension. If I add an individual account in VS, I could upload it. If I add an enterprise account, in details window I can upload a p12 extension file.

Does it help? Can't add ios distribution certificate

Before reading that post, I could create the distribution certificate using Xcode in a Mac. From there, when I connect to Apple account, the team role does appear as Admin (so maybe a bug in VS2022). I created the certificate using Xcode then and later, I have connected to Apple account using VS2022 but distribution certificate appears as it is not in the key chain. How can I add to the chain?

that link did not help. Finally I could create the distribution certificate using XCode in a Mac. that way, it is listed in the certificate dialog of VS but with the error "It is not in the key chains"
